# What kind of connectors do I need for my keg, and where can I get them?

Tags: keg

I have a European Sankey keg with a Type S tap, but my CO2 container only has connectors for a ball-lock valve.

What connectors do I need to get the tap pictured attached to my CO2?  It would help to know what the individual components are called in German too.

Note that this: http://www.kegworks.com/sankey-to-ball-lock-disconnect-conversion-kit-778-p177420 is exactly what I need, except it's only for a US tap and has the wrong threads for the European tap, which I believe are 5/8".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.kegworks.com/connectors-for-beer-lines-1170-p16540?featured=&_s_icmp=KWinternalrecs) looks like it would attach to your tap, then you just need to replicate the fittings you have on your current CO2 set up...  I emailed kegworks to confirm it would work for a European Sankey keg. I received an email response from customer care at kegworks who said it would fit and the only difference between European and American Sankeys is the fitting that goes into the keg itself. That said the fitting in your original post may work fine. sounds like either one might be worth a shot..

I have solved similar problems by taking my hardware to the helpful folks at [Hose & Fittings](http://www.hoseandfittingsetc.com/).  The shop in Reno conveniently had a brewer on staff!

good luck!

Comment: Thanks @mike, but what makes you think the linked connector would fit my tap?  I see no measurements that indicate the size of the female component; the 3/16" refers to the line out.  Unfortunately Reno's a bit distant right now...

Comment: Hi @keflavich,  I was assuming the European Sankey was adhering to a standard, are you concerned that it doesn't?  I'm not that familiar with those taps.  I think Hose & Fittings is the way to go if you haven't had luck with off the shelf fittings.

I was looking closer at your picture, is that a removable thread coming of the side?  You could always take that to home depot to get the thread size and count...

Comment: the problem is I'm in Germany.  There are no Home Depots or Hose & Fittings around.  You're right that there's a removable thread; the one underneath is the same size as the top.  I think the two are both 5/8", and the removable has a male component that is 3/4"

Comment: Hi @keflavich.  I could see how your location would make my Home Depot idea a very bad one :)  Since I suggested that fitting, I emailed kegworks to confirm it would work for a European Sankey keg.  I received a response from the guy at kegworks who said it would fit and the only difference between European and American Sankeys is the fitting that goes into the keg itself.  That said the fitting in your original post may work fine.  sounds like either one might be worth a shot...

Comment: That's great info!  Edit it into your answer and I'll accept it; I've never found that sort of info about taps anywhere else (I think most sites just assume you know it)

Comment: Hey @keflavich can you post your success/failure with this project?  I'd love to know it was more than just banter...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the ends on my tap are 5/8", and on the gas in there is an additional component that converts 5/8" to 3/4" and has a one-way valve in between, which is necessary. I did not convert to a ball-lock system.

I bought these components, and now everything works, though I still can't disassemble the keg:
http://www.candirect.de/CO2-Anschlussschlauch-fuer-KEGS-mit-3-4-Muttern
http://www.candirect.de/Mini-Zapfhahn-mit-Bier-KEG-Zapfkopfanschluss